# XSLT: How to get the attribute value of Table colspec to the individual Table cells?

Tags: xslt

Please suggest to get the attribute value of colspec to the 'td' of same position with respect to 'colspec'.

For Example third 'td' should get the attribute of third 'colspec'.

XML:

```
<article>

<table-wrap>
    <table>

        <colspec align="center"/>
        <colspec align="left"/>
        <colspec align="right"/>
        <colspec align="center"/>
        <colspec align="left"/>

        <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td>01</td>
            <td>02</td>
            <td>03</td>
            <td>04</td>
            <td>05</td>
        </tr>

        </tbody>
    </table>
</table-wrap>
```

XSLT:

```
<xsl:template match="td">
    <xsl:variable name="varIndex">
        <xsl:value-of select="count(preceding-sibling::td)+1"/>
    </xsl:variable>

    <xsl:variable name="varColspecAlign">
        <xsl:value-of select="ancestor::table/colspec[$varIndex]/@align"/>
    </xsl:variable>

        <td>
            <xsl:attribute name="align"><xsl:value-of select="$varColspecAlign"/></xsl:attribute>
            <xsl:apply-templates/>
        </td>
</xsl:template>
```

Required Out Put is:

```
        <colspec align="center"/>
        <colspec align="left"/>
        <colspec align="right"/>
        <colspec align="center"/>
        <colspec align="left"/>

        <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td align="center">01</td>
            <td align="left">02</td>
            <td align="right">03</td>
            <td align="center">04</td>
            <td align="left">05</td>
        </tr>

        </tbody>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

<del>I am not really sure *why* your template doesn't work as expected</del> . (**I am now - see the edit below**). However, I do know how to fix it. Change this:

```
   <xsl:variable name="varIndex">
        <xsl:value-of select="count(preceding-sibling::td)+1"/>
    </xsl:variable>
```

to:

```
<xsl:variable name="varIndex" select="count(preceding-sibling::td)+1"/>
```

### ---

**EDIT**
The reason why this makes a difference is this: When you define a variable the way you did, the data type of the variable is "result tree fragment". The other way declares a variable of type "number".

This has a direct consequence when using the variable as a predicate: if the variable is a RTF, the expression `[$variable]` will return a boolean value of either true() or false(), depending on the variable being empty or not. More precisely, a RTF cannot be empty (it contains at least one node, otherwise it would not be a RTF) - so the result is **always** true().

This means that your expression:

```
<xsl:value-of select="ancestor::table/colspec[$varIndex]/@align"/>
```

is actually evaluated as:

```
<xsl:value-of select="ancestor::table/colspec[true()]/@align"/>
```

In other words, the predicate does nothing and the expression is equivalent to:

```
<xsl:value-of select="ancestor::table/colspec/@align"/>
```

which (in XSLT 1.0) will select the @align value of the **first** colspec element in document order.

Converting the RTF to a number, either explicitly:

```
<xsl:value-of select="ancestor::table/colspec[number($varIndex)]/@align"/>
```

or implicitly:

```
<xsl:value-of select="ancestor::table/colspec[position()=$varIndex]/@align"/>
```

would also result in getting the result that you expect.

### ---

While you're at it, change the other variable to this format too, because it's more efficient this way (I've been told).

Speaking of efficiency, the best way to get "related" data is through a **key**. Try:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" 
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output method='xml' version='1.0' encoding='utf-8' indent='yes'/>

<xsl:key name="align" match="colspec" use="count(preceding-sibling::colspec)" />

<xsl:template match="@*|node()">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="td">
    <xsl:variable name="varIndex" select="count(preceding-sibling::td)"/>
        <td>
            <xsl:attribute name="align"><xsl:value-of select="key('align', $varIndex)/@align"/></xsl:attribute>
            <xsl:apply-templates/>
        </td>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: Hi Sir, Sorry for late reply. Thanks a lot for your suggestions. Now with the help of your code, I am able to get the required OUTPUT. It is working fine.

Answer (score -1):

try the position function, and for that you should use the foreach function as well.
the reason is that the template isn't changing it's context and therefor the position will not increase...
here a code for example:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
    <xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
    xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
    <xsl:template match="//table">
        <xsl:for-each select="//td">
            <xsl:variable name="varIndex" select="position()"/>
            <xsl:variable name="varColspecAlign">
                <xsl:value-of select="//colspec[$varIndex]/@align"/>
            </xsl:variable>

            <td>
               <xsl:attribute name="align"><xsl:value-of select="$varColspecAlign"/></xsl:attribute>
            </td>
        </xsl:for-each>


    </xsl:template>

    </xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: "parent::tr/td/position()", can I use?. For this also I am not getting the 'td' s position.

Comment: @knightsb Variables in XSLT are immutable but you declare the same variable twice. That could throw errors in some processors. Also the double slashes in your XPath's are very inefficient and could also cause issues depending on the XML so I wouldn't recommend using that either. Otherwise, it looks like it produces the correct output at least.

Comment: Matthew, the first varible declarition was not needed and i took it off (copy paste mistake) as for the '//' it is just for explanation porpoise and like Rudramuni wrote 'ancestor::table' will work just fine.

Comment: It is not fetching required attribute from colspec array